# how does the .Tpo file generate?why there is "NO Such file or directory"?

Tags: c, configure, autoconf, automake

output of `make`:

```
Making all in access/
gcc  -g -O2   -o fileOpt fileOpt.o  
Making all in executor/
gcc  -g -O2   -o executor execFilter.o execJoin.o execMain.o execNode.o execProject.o execScan.o execSort.o execUtil.o  
Making all in index/
gcc  -g -O2   -o index b_plus_tree.o  
Making all in nodes/
gcc  -g -O2   -o nodes nodes.o  
Making all in optimizer/
gcc  -g -O2   -o optimizer optimizer.o path.o  
Making all in parse/
gcc  -g -O2   -o parser analyze.o check.o gram.o parser.o scan.o  
Making all in posql/
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE -I. -I.. -I /Users/YOuth/Program/posql/src/backend/include     -g -O2 -MT ../util/transfrom.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/../util/transfrom.Tpo -c -o ../util/transfrom.o ../util/transfrom.c
error: error opening '.deps/../util/transfrom.Tpo': Error opening output file '.deps/../util/transfrom.Tpo': No such file or director
```

I found in other folder(access/ index/ ...),It also has no `.Tpo` file in the `.dep` folder? Why it just util cannot find?

```
ls util/
Makefile    Makefile.am Makefile.in transfrom.c util.c
```

`transfrom.c`:

```
#include "util/transfrom.h"
#include "util/datatype.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void strToDate(Date* date , char* str){
    ....
}
```

My question is how the `Tpo` generate? Is there any possible even obvious mistakes? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Amongst other problems with the listed makefile(s), this parameter: `.deps/../util/transfrom.Tpo` is very unlikely to be correct.

It says: in the sub directory `.deps` (notice the `.`) 
step up one directory (that is where the makefile is) then step down to the util directory.

Then generate the file `transfrom.Tpo`.

Hummm. Perhaps it is just a typo, but I suspect `transform.Tpo` is wrong as is the path being presented.

However, of interest is (normally) there is a dependency file for each source file, not just one dependency file.  And it is usually best to name those dependency files the same root name as the associated source file, with a unique extension, like `.d`

I would suggest the generation of dependancy file(s) be done in a separate make file rule, using `-M -MF <file name>.c`

Do not use `-MP` as that causes `gcc` to gen a target for each file and to not supply any dependency(s).

The gcc parameter details can be found at:
http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html#SEC3

The following is a make file (actually a pair of makefiles) that handle 
generation of dependencies, compiling, linking in each sub directory and the main directory.  They use `sed` rather than `gcc` to generate the dependency files, but the above info will enable you to tweak that rule.

This is the top level makefile:
Note: the `allDirectories` macro is a list of the sub directories,
which would would have to tweak for your list of sub directories

```
SHELL = /bin/sh


#  note: this makefile.mak needs to be run from the ./src directory
# of the GOT4 directory tree


SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      :=  mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -W

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

LIBS    :=  -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm -lcrypto



.PHONY: AllDirectories
# the following statement needs to be edited as
# subdirectories are added/deleted/re-named
AllDirectories := \
    CommandConfiguration \
    Communication \
    MainScheduler \
    RetrieveCDSLog \
    RetrieveEventRecorderLog \
    RetrieveGPS \
    QESRouter

.PHONY: all
#all: $(OBJ) $(AllDirectories)
#   $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
#    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f makefile.mak name=Tsk_$d all ); )

all: $(OBJ) $(AllDirectories)
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d all ); )



#
# create dependancy files
#
%.d: %.c
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
#
%.o: %.c %.d
    #
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I.
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    #



.PHONY: clean
#clean: $(AllDirectories)
#   # ========== start clean activities ==========
#   rm -f *.o
#   rm -f $(name).map
#   rm -f $(name)
#   rm -f *.d
#   $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
#    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f makefile.mak clean ); )
#   # ========== end clean activities ==========

clean: $(AllDirectories)
    # ========== start clean activities ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    rm -f ../bin/Tsk_*
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d clean ); )
    # ========== end clean activities ==========



.PHONY: install
#install: $(AllDirectories)
#   # ========== start install activities ==========
#   $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
#    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f makefile.mak clean ); )
#   # ========== end install activities ==========

install: $(AllDirectories)
    # ========== start install activities ==========
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d install ); )
    # ========== end install activities ==========



# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that file
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```

This is the makefile that goes in each sub directory.

```
SHELL = /bin/sh


BINDIR  :=  /home/user/bin


.PHONY: all
all : $(BINDIR)/$(name) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot


#
# macro of all *.c files 
# (NOTE:
# (the following 'wildcard' will pick up ALL .c files
# (like FileHeader.c and FunctionHeader.c 
# (which should not be part of the build
# (so be sure no unwanted .c files in directory
# (or change the extension
#
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


COMMON_OBJ := $(wildcard ../*.o)
#COMMON_SRC := $(wildcard ../*.c)
#COMMON_OBJ := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.o)
#COMMON_DEP := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.d)
#COMMON_INC := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.h)

MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp -f

MV      := mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -W

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

#LIBS    :=  -lidn -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm
LIBS    :=   -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm -lcrypto



#
# link the .o files into the executable 
# using the linker flags
# -- explicit rule
#
$(name): $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #



# note:
# using MV rather than CP results in all executables being re-made everytime
$(BINDIR)/$(name): $(name)
    #
    # ======= $(name) Copy Start =========
    $(CP) $(name) $(BINDIR)/
    # ======= $(name) Copy Done ==========
    #



#
#create dependancy files -- inference rule
# list makefile.mak as dependancy so changing makfile forces rebuild
#
%.d: %.c 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



# 
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 



.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    # ========== DONE ==========



.PHONY: install
install: all

# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependencies for that .c file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```